# C# Algebra formula to find pattern

Tags: c#, algebra

I am running some *Running Totals* functions which need to create a pattern but I am seriously struggling to find the right formula.

*It is not a homework, just look at my profile* ...

**MinRow** Represents for me the Row-1 where my Count should start, *if MinRow = 3 I should start to count from 4*

**K** is a constant value that I can use to calculate X

```
Example A:
MinRow = 2, K = 3
Expected
|---Row---|--X--|
|    3    |  2  |
|    4    |  4  |
|    5    |  6  |

Example B:
MinRow = 1, K = 5
Expected
|---Row---|--X--|
|    2    |  4  |
|    3    |  8  |
|    4    | 12  |

Example C:
MinRow = 27, K = 2
Expected
|---Row---|--X--|
|   28    |  1  |
|   29    |  2  |
|   30    |  3  |
```

Example B can be solved using `X = (K * (Row-MinRow)) - (Row-MinRow)` but it does not work for Example A or C.
Do you think I can address these patterns using a common formula?

Comment: The formula you provided works for all 3 examples. Check again? Your (simplified) formula is `X = (K - 1) * (Row - MinRow)`.

Comment: True, probably by posting here I didn't pay attention on it

Comment: I'd recommend that you or the mods close this question so that people know that it has been done with <strike>and don't post answers like below</strike>.

Answer (score 0):

As @Evil Tak pointed out, this can be simplified to

```
X = (K - 1) * (Row - MinRow)
```

and works for all three of your examples.